# Can't adjust padding/spacing above and below PayPal button?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, padding

I have several PayPal Add to Cart buttons on the eCommerce section of my site: http://drray.com/bookstore/ and there is so much spacing above and below each button and it doesn't seem to be caused or controlled by any CSS properties. This is a WordPress site. I can't figure out if I can fix this spacing issue or if I even have any control over it.

The buttons are dynamic and I get the code directly from PayPal's site. It doesn't appear that I can control the button's appearance in any way from PayPal.

Any advice on how to fix this extra spacing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is becase there are `<br>` tags in the form:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CTXUPNCPMQXPU">
<br>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<br>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"><br>
</form>
```

Removing them will remove the extra space:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CTXUPNCPMQXPU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<br>` tags within the paypal form code can help as they add new lines.

You could further reduce the spacing by adding this to the paypal images (modify the pixel amounts to what seems right for you:

```
style="margin-bottom:-10px;margin-top:-10px;"
```

An example of how to use it would be:

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="margin-bottom: -10px;margin-top:-10px;">
```